# How to extract aria-label value using java?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

This is example :

```
String document = "<div class=\"tertiary\" if=\"tertiaryHyperlinks.length\"> \n" +
                " <a rel=\"nofollow\" data-vehicleid=\"5651083350\" data-saved=\"false\" data-action=\"save\" role=\"button\" aria-pressed=\"false\" merchandising-savelink=\"currVehicleId: 5651083350; isSaved: false; saveLabel: Save; savedLabel:Saved\" class=\"vehicle-save\" repeat=\"tertiaryHyperlinks\" name=\"a55ec147-0c31-45ff-bb61-0c56e7214967\" href data-linkid=\"a55ec147-0c31-45ff-bb61-0c56e7214967\" title=\"SAVE\" target>Save</a> \n" +
                " <a rel=\"nofollow\" aria-disabled=\"false\" role=\"button\" aria-pressed=\"false\" merchandising-comparevehicle data-vehicleid=\"5651083350\" data-action=\"compare\" data-saved=\"false\" href=\"#vehicle-compare-cart\" aria-label=\"Compare new 2024 BMW 228i 228i Gran Coupe VIN WBA53AK02R7N16670\" class=\"vehicle-compare\" repeat=\"tertiaryHyperlinks\" name=\"7534c28e-3ab6-45ab-bf5d-091698d4c5e0\" data-linkid=\"7534c28e-3ab6-45ab-bf5d-091698d4c5e0\" title=\"COMPARE\" target>COMPARE</a> \n" +
                "</div>";
```

I tried with

```
Document document1 = Jsoup.parse(document);
String div = document1.select("div.tertiary").attr("aria-label").text();
```

But I am getting empty response instead of "Compare new 2024 BMW 228i 228i Gran Coupe VIN WBA53AK02R7N16670".

Comment: What is `document1`?

Comment: Can you [edit] and improve the question, including providing more detail about the problem and the code, and strive to improve the code's formatting and readability? The [ask] link can help guide you in this.

Comment: How are you parsing the string? Are you using Jsoup or HTMLEditorKit or something else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using (it's been a while since I did HTML parsing), but `aria-label` isn't on the div, it's on the `<a>` _within_ the div. Do you need to do something like `document.select("div.tertiary a").attr("aria-label")`? (And if so, I don't know how to say in your library "the second `<a>`" instead of the first, or if you need to.)

Comment: I am using Jsuop. Thanks yshavit this is working. Now I am getting Compare new 2024 BMW 228i 228i Gran Coupe VIN WBA53AK02R7N16670

Comment: `String result = document.split("aria\\-label=\"")[1].split("\" class=\"")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some relevant documents regarding the *Jsoup* *selector-syntax*.

- *[Use selector-syntax to find elements: jsoup Java HTML parser](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)*
- *[Selector (jsoup Java HTML Parser 1.16.1 API)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)*

You can use the following to return the first anchor within *div tertiary* that contains the *aria-label* attribute.

```java
Document document1 = Jsoup.parse(document);
Elements elements = document1.select("div.tertiary a");
String div = elements.attr("aria-label");
```

Output

```
Compare new 2024 BMW 228i 228i Gran Coupe VIN WBA53AK02R7N16670
```